# Uniform smoothness inequality for Schatten norms

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, matrices, matrix-analysis, norms

I've previously asked this question on stack exchange.

I'm looking for a proof of the inequality

$$
\left[ \frac12(\left\|A+B\right\|_p^p + \left\|A-B\right\|_p^p)\right]^{2/p} \leq \left\|A\right\|_p^2 +C_p \left\|B\right\|_p^2
$$

where A and B are complex matrices of the same size, $\left\| .\right\|_p$ refers to the Schatten p-norm,  p$\geq 2$, and $C_p=p-1$.

I have a reference for the opposite inequality when $1\leq p \leq 2$ but no mention of the one above. Are the two somehow equivalent? Am I missing an easy argument to follow one out of the other?

Comment: I do mean $\geq$ instead of $\leq$. Sorry if it is worded strangely. Here is the reference just for good measure: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01231769
The statement is that of Theorem 1.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. No, the formulation is clear enough, just the fact itself confused me somehow.

Answer (score 3):

According to the Pisier-Xu survey "Non-commutative $L^p$ spaces" https://www.zbmath.org/?q=an%3A1046.46048, this is proved in

Ball, Keith; Carlen, Eric A.; Lieb, Elliott H.
Sharp uniform convexity and smoothness inequalities for trace norms.
Invent. Math. 115, No. 3, 463-482 (1994).

https://www.zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0803.47037

Edit: I just saw that you are mentionning the exact same reference in the comments, sorry. I guess that what you are looking for is Lemma 5 in the Ball-Carlen-Lieb paper.

Comment: I should have included this in my original question (my bad) but this is exactly the paper I'm referring to as proving the case of $1\leq p\leq 2$ but not the other case. I have also seen this work referenced to prove both cases but I just don't see it.

Comment: @ludoer Sorry, I read your question a bit too fast. Does the edit answer your question ?

Comment: Just for clarification: Does the proof for theorem 1 imply what I've referred to as the opposite inequality (so the case $1\leq p \leq 2$) and Lemma 5 then says that the two cases are equivalent (for any normed space)?

Comment: @ludoer Yes, you are perfectly right. (Lemma 5 relates the convexity properties of $X$ with the smothness properties of its dual, and here we apply it to $S^p$ and $S^{p'}$).

Comment: one (hopefully) last question:
Is $S^{p'}$ the dual space to $S^p$ or is it simply a matter of the dual space of a space of matrices is the same space transposed, but we don't care about it being transposed as it doesn't matter for our Schatten norms, and then we choose the norms we want for each space, where the choice is the $p$-norm for one space and the $p'$-norm for the other? I realize this is not worded well but I hope the question still comes across.

Comment: Yes, $S^{p'}$ is the dual of $S^p$. This follows from Hölder's inequality for matrices, see for example the survey by Pisier-Xu in my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!